# Why is the absolute positioned element not obeying positioning guidelines?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm following a tutorial on how to build a website in dreamweaver (https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/how-to/make-website-pt6-web-links-navigation.html) However I'm trying to understand why a certain step in the tutorial works as it does.

I have an absolutely positioned element #navlink, here's it's position in the DOM structure:

```
nav 
    h2 #menulink
    ul #navlink
nav
```

visually looking at the result, ul#navlinks gets removed from the page as per absolute flag, but instead of getting anchored next to the last positioned element, which is the html page (since no element above ul is positioned relative or otherwise) it jumps to the h2#menulink that is above it in dom.

I'm not sure if it's just a mistake in my code and that I am inedvertantly positioning the h2 or nav element in some way, or that I overlooked some other reason of why the document flow attachment point is being overriden, but I cannot find the mistake no matter how many times I go through the code.

This is a link to a full source code as well as the rendered page as I have it in jfiddle:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5d8bde1f196b919dab297560ff85b072

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Your code is correct, and so is the browser. For `absolute` positioning, it is anchored "next to the last positioned element" horizontally only when `left` or `right` property is defined, and vertically only when `top` or `bottom` property is defined.

If there is no `top`, `bottom`, `left` or `right` defined for `ul#navlink`, it will be "removed from page", but positioned as `position: static`.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation.